# How to send Json Object to ViewModel in .Net Core Rest api

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ViewModel which is initialized dto. I want to send json object from postman with their values but c# object can not take values and is set null. How can i do that ?

```
public class RegisterUserVm
{
   public UserDto User { get; set; }

   public RegisterUserVm()
   {
      User = new UserDto();
   }
} 

public class UserDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Firstname { get; set; }
   public string Lastname { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Telephone { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
[Route("RegisterUser")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> RegisterUser([FromBody] RegisterUserVm vm)
{
   var registeredUser = await userBusiness.RegisterUser(new RegisterUserCommand
                {
                    User = vm.User
                });

                return registeredUser.Result;
}
```

Comment: You mixed up the request and viewmodel classes. The *input* to the action is the request DTO. The *return* value would be the ViewModel. And unless `RegisterUser` returns a `Task<Task<UserDto>>` your code won't even run because `registeredUser` should already be a `UserDto`

Comment: You have to post the request you used in Postman, otherwise it's impossible to guess what's wrong. Almost certainly, the body doesn't match the `RegisterUserVm` class, ie it isn't a single object whose single `User` property contains an object that matches UserDto. Perhaps there are fields missing, or perhaps the body is a quoted string instead of a JSON string

Comment: I understood. I post the request by using Postman. I will change viewmodel.

Comment: Can you update the image how you submit the data in postman ?

Answer (score -1):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("RegisterUser")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody] RegisterUserVm vm)
{
   var registeredUser = await userBusiness.RegisterUser(new RegisterUserCommand
                {
                    User = vm.User
                });

                var resultModel = registeredUser.Result.ToResultModel();
                return Ok(resultModel);

}
```